# How do I use local variable which is in POST method in nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

These are modules I have used:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { dirname } = require('path');
const { request } = require('http');
const { response } = require('express');
const urlencoded = require('body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded');
const res = require('express/lib/response');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
```

This is my post request

```
app.post('/src/login.html' ,function(req , res){
  var prn = req.body.prn;
  var password = req.body.password;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE prn=? AND password=?',[prn , password],function(error, results, fields){
    if (error) throw error;
    if(results.length > 0){
      res.redirect('/src/dashboard-student');
    }else{
      res.redirect('/src/login.html');
    }
  });  
});
var PRN = prn;
console.log(PRN);
```

I'm getting an error:

> var PRN = prn;
> ^
>
> ReferenceError: prn is not defined
>
> at Object. (C:\Users\Niranjan\Desktop\SY CSE\Seminar-II\SIS\Project\app.js:115:11)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

I want to store data caught in var prn to any global variable so I can use it in any other requests. How do I do that in nodejs?

Comment: Define the variable _before_ your `app.post()` handler (eg `let PRN;`) and then assign it within the handler... `PRN = req.body.prn;`. You won't be able to log the value until it's set though

Comment: Why do you need to store the value outside of the request handler?

Comment: Yes I've done as you said but it throws same error as before

Comment: I want to use that data in other post request

Comment: There is absolutely no way it _"throws the same error"_ so what did you _actually_ use in your code? Please [edit] your question

Comment: So is there any way that I can get a variable inside a local variable outside its scope using any function or anything?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use [session storage](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html). Otherwise, the value stored in the variable will be the same for **every** request, no matter where it comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using Express, you can make use of the session. You can do the following `req.session.prn = req.body.prn;` which will save the variable to the current session.

Then, you'll be able to pass the variable to other routes like so

```
        return res.render("/", {
            prn: req.session.prn
        });
```

Which can then be referenced by whatever templating engine your using in your view.

Comment: Yes !! It worked when I used sessions :)

Comment: Please mark question as answered if it helped you solve your problem :)